# Nginx+FastCGI+Django Remove URL Prefix before passing to Django

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

I've setup Nginx to fastcgi_pass to Django and don't want to serve Django from "/". I want to prefix the URLs with something like "/django/sample/" but then have Nginx remove that prefix before it gets passed to Django - this way Django's internals will act like it's actually serving from "/".

I've tried updating the Django app to include the prefix in the URLs routed, like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  '^', include(base_urlpatterns), # iff you wish to maintain the un-prefixed URL's too
  '^your_prefix/', include(base_urlpatterns),
)
```

And I currently do a fastcgi_pass like so:

```
#django sample
location /django/sample {
include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8024;
}
```

But this isn't a graceful solution as any URL in my django app then has to make sure to include a prefix like "/django/sample". And it also means that when I run locally VS on the server the URLs may need to be different.

I build quite a few django apps that'll be running from one server and don't want to always have to do this tom-foolery with URLs and remember to update all the URLs in Django.

I've been googling for a while trying to figure out how to do this with nginx but haven't seen anything.

So, I'm looking to use Nginx to remove the "/django/sample" in the request before it gets passed to Django. Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way round. There's no reason to remove the prefix before passing to Django: as long as you configure your server correctly, Django will be aware of it, and will automatically use it in things like the `{% url %}` tag and `reverse()` call (which of course you're using for all your URL references internally).

The documentation for deploying with FastCGI gives some details of [how to set the prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#forcing-the-url-prefix-to-a-particular-value), in particular the advice that if you can't get it to work any other way, you can explicitly set `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` to the value of your prefix.